# Printing a WinForm Landscape to the default printer

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to print a user form in VB.NET on the click of a button.

I have added the 'PrintForm' powerpack and simply used :

```
PrintForm1.Print()
```

this will print the form into the preview window however lops a chunk of the image off the right had side

Is there a simple line of code that can accompany this to ensure it is printed landscape?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)
```

Actually code like printing form is very easy to find on GOOGLE.com. Some time we got a bunch of code, but if you seriously and patient to search it. You can find all of you need except even you think it's impossible

Comment: this simply doesnt work and does exactly the same as PrintForm1.Print()

Answer (score 0):

Before you print the form, try to setting it before.
Try this one :

```
Me.PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
```